# Converting pandas dataframe to list of key value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
 col1 col2 
0  a     11
1  b     12
2  b     13
3  a     14
4  a     15
```

and I want to convert it into a list which should be like

```
myList = {'a':['11','14','15'],'b':['12','13']}
```

Please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by the first column, collect the values of the second column into lists, convert the result into a dictionary:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list).to_dict()
#{'a': ['11', '14', '15'], 'b': ['12', '13']}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for help. 
Is there any other simple way by which I can also add a word 'Any' in the produced list? Preferably I want to add it in while converting it from pandas to list.

# { 'a' : ['Any', '11', '14', '15'], 'b': ['Any', '12', '13']}

I am trying to do it with loops but not able to do it till now. 
Please suggest, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution from `itertools`

```
import itertools

l=df.sort_values('col1').values.tolist()
{k: [x[1] for x in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(l,lambda x : x[0])}
{'a': [11, 14, 15], 'b': [12, 13]}
```